# Is there a way to deal with unknown generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I have this code

```
public interface IConsumable<T> {
  void Consume(T item);
}

public interface IProducer<T> {
  IConsumable<T> Consumer { get; set; }
  void Produce();
}

public class MyClass : MyType, 
  IConsumable<ISpecifcItem>
{
  public void Consume(ISpecificItem item) { ... }
}

public class MySpecificItemProducer
  : IProducer<ISpecificItem> {
  public IConsumable<ISpecificItem> Consumer { get; set; }
  public void Produce() {
    ISpecificItem myItem = new MyVerySpecificItem();
    Consumer.Consume(myItem);
  }
}
```

Then I'm having a controller that takes any `MyType`, discovers all types of `IConsumable<>` that it implements and gets the type of the generic type parameter. With this list of types it discovers all producers that implement `IProducer<TParam>`. That's not difficult:

```
var consumerTypes =
    myType.GetType().GetInterfaces()
    .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
    .Where(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
        typeof(IConsumable<>));

  if (consumerTypes.Any()) {
    var instanceTypes = consumerTypes
      .Select(x => x.GetGenericArguments().First())
      .Select(x => typeof(IProducer<>).MakeGenericType(x));
    // for each of those types discover classes where 
    // it assignable from
    // and instantiate the class using the Activator
  }
```

But the problem is, how do I set the Consumer property of the producer? The producer instance is an object to me, I can't cast it to an `IProducer<T>`, because I can't use T like a variable.

I can do it with reflection `producerInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Consumer").SetValue(producerInstance, consumerInstance, null);` but I wanted to know if there's another way?

Interestingly, this failed at runtime:

```
MyClass consumerInstance;
dynamic test = producerInstance;
test.Consumer = consumerInstance;
```

It complained that the type of consumerInstance was incompatible to the type of the property.

EDIT: The dynamic example worked only when consumerInstance was also a dynamic, e.g.:

```
dynamic testC = consumerInstance;
dynamic testP = producerInstance;
testP.Consumer = testC;
```

Comment: Your dynamic code works fine for me.

Comment: hmm okay, I tried it just once briefly, maybe something else then.

Comment: I followed up on the dynamic example and found out that it worked when I made the assignee also dynamic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, without refactoring the code you provided, you cannot solve the problem without more reflection (as you have done). However, you could use reflection before you set the consumer property if it makes it more readable for you.

```
var method = GetType().GetMethod("Process");
var genericType = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments().First();
var invocable = method.MakeGenericMethod(genericType);

invocable.Invoke(this, new object[] { producer, consumer });

public void Process<T>(IProducer<T> producer, IConsumable<T> consumer)
{
  producer.Consumer = consumer;
}
```

Are you giving >1 IConsumable to MyType and just altering the generic type argument? I assume you are because you get a list of those interfaces. I don't know where you get your producers from, but the only way to not use reflection is to stay out of it. You could consider forcing each 'MyType' to provide a method that would 'setup' a list of producers (MyType internally would know all of it's own consumable types). Depending on where you pull the producers from (internal to MyType or external) you may have to do the following:

```
public interface IProducer { }

public interface IProducer<T> : IProducer
{
  IConsumable<T> Consumer { get; set; }
  void Produce();
}

public interface IConsumableProvider
{
  void SetupProducers(params IProducer[] producers);
}

public class MyType : 
  IConsumable<int>,
  IConsumable<double>,
  IConsumableProvider
{
  public void Consume(int item)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public void Consume(double item)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public void SetupProducers(params IProducer[] producers)
  {
    (producers[0] as IProducer<int>).Consumer = (this as IConsumable<int>);
    (producers[1] as IProducer<double>).Consumer = (this as IConsumable<double>);
  }
}
```

I'm not in love with the solution, but I feel an optimal solution would require more information about your current code base - else I would give an answer too divergent to what you already have.

Comment: Thanks, to be honest I had a reflection-less solution before, but that required non-generic interfaces on top and some casting. It also added a few methods to the interface that I didn't like to be there.

Comment: I like your solution in some way as it puts the string reference and the so referenced method in the same class. It's a bit more complicated to setup though as you say, but this makes me feel much safer. When someone refactors the property name, the change will be automatically forwarded.

Comment: I have to add, that unfortunately it didn't work in Release builds. I don't know why and I got too little time to follow up on it, but the method could not be discovered (got the right binding flags though). So, I wrote it by using the dynamic keyword since that's at least the most readable solution.